# mvprobit -How to obtain marginal effects

Tags: stata

I have just run a model using mvprobit for innovation1 and innovation2.
Now, I am very interested in identifying the marginal effects of the covariates on the probit predicted joint probability of success (innovation1 =1 and innovation2=1) and failure (innovation1=0 and innovation2=0). Is it using margins command?

Thanks so much for your help!

I tried running a reg with the results of mvppred pall, pall as outcome variable.

Comment: I would ask this on Statalist. `mvprobit` is community-contributed and to the best of my knowledge neither author is active here to comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to have more context: however, this should work.
Note that since the command you use is not native to Stata you must use Monte Carlo methods.

```
// Simulate Data
clear
set obs 1000
gen var1 = rnormal()
gen var2 = rnormal()
gen e1 = rnormal()
gen e2 = rnormal() + 0.5 * e1
gen innovation1 = (0.5 + 0.3*var1 + 0.2*var2 + e1 > 0)
gen innovation2 = (0.2 + 0.4*var1 + 0.1*var2 + e2 > 0)

// Fit mvprobit model
mvprobit (innovation1 = var1 var2) (innovation2 = var1 var2)

// Get estimated parameters and covariance matrix
matrix b = e(b)
matrix V = e(V)

// Define Monte Carlo simulation program
capture program drop sim_marginal_effects
program define sim_marginal_effects, rclass
    // Simulate coefficients
    matrix b_sim = b + cholesky(V)*rnormal(rows(b),1)
    
    // Calculate joint probability for (1,1) and (0,0)
    // Insert calculation based on b_sim here
    // ...
    
    // Store results
    return scalar(p11 = ...)
    return scalar(p00 = ...)
end

// Run the simulation
simulate p11=r(p11) p00=r(p00), reps(1000): sim_marginal_effects

// Calculate average marginal effects and confidence intervals
// ...
```